# An sql query returns empty when it should not?

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I have this sql query which perform an foreing key validation, and validated whether both entries uphold a certain standard.

The query should return something (since the data I pass in should fail), as long there is data in the database.

But what I've noticed is that, when I in the same transaction insert data and then perform the validation in the same transaction the validation query returns nothing, when it in actuality should return numerous rows.

if I do the same step as above, meaning I already have committed data in the database, and insert the same data, my validation script returns the excepted rows?

is there any limitations in regards to using transcations?

in here I insert data

```
private IEnumerable<long> PersistEntityRegistrations(IEnumerable<EntityRegistration> payload, string entityName, NpgsqlTransaction transaction)
{
    IEnumerable<string> customAttributeNames = GetEntitySpecificAttributes(entityName);
    IEnumerable<string> allAttributeNames =
        EntityRegistration.standardAttributeNames.Union(customAttributeNames);
    var insertNewRegistrationSql =
        @$"INSERT INTO ""{entityName}_registration"" ({string.Join(",", allAttributeNames)})
            SELECT * FROM unnest({string.Join(",", allAttributeNames.Select(x => "@" + x))})
            RETURNING row_id;";
    NpgsqlCommand insertRegistrations = new NpgsqlCommand(insertNewRegistrationSql, transaction.Connection, transaction);

    DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;

    NpgsqlParameter entity_id = new NpgsqlParameter("entity_id", payload.Where(x => x.EntityId.HasValue).Select(x => x.EntityId ?? 0).ToArray());
    insertRegistrations.Parameters.Add(entity_id);
    NpgsqlParameter entryName = new NpgsqlParameter("entry_name", payload.Select(x => x.EntryName).ToArray());
    insertRegistrations.Parameters.Add(entryName);
    NpgsqlParameter registrationBy = new NpgsqlParameter("registration_by", payload.Select(x => x.RegistrationBy).ToArray());
    insertRegistrations.Parameters.Add(registrationBy);
    NpgsqlRange<DateTime>[] valid = payload.Select(x => x.Valid).ToArray();
    insertRegistrations.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("valid", valid));
    NpgsqlRange<DateTime>[] registration = payload.Select(x => new NpgsqlRange<DateTime>(now, lowerBoundIsInclusive: true, DateTime.MaxValue, upperBoundIsInclusive: true)).ToArray();
    insertRegistrations.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("registration", registration));

    Entity entity = schemaService.ReadSchema().Entities.SingleOrDefault(x => x.InternalName == entityName);
    Relation relation = schemaService.ReadSchema().Relations.SingleOrDefault(x => x.InternalName == entityName);
    ICollection<Attribute> entityAttributeDefinitions = entity != null ? entity.Attributes : relation.Attributes ;

    foreach (Attribute attributeDefinition in entityAttributeDefinitions)
    {                 
        IEnumerable<object> attributeValues = payload.Where(x => x.Attributes.ContainsKey(attributeDefinition.InternalName))
            .Select(x => x.Attributes[attributeDefinition.InternalName]);

        switch (attributeDefinition.Type)
        {
            case DataType.Dropdown:
            case DataType.WeekDay:
            case DataType.Text:
                var castedStringValues = attributeValues.Cast<string?>().ToArray();
                insertRegistrations.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter(attributeDefinition.InternalName, castedStringValues));
                break;
            case DataType.Number:
                var castedNumberValues = attributeValues.Cast<decimal>().ToArray();
                insertRegistrations.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter(attributeDefinition.InternalName, castedNumberValues));
                break;
            case DataType.Lookup:
                var castedLookupValues = attributeValues.Cast<decimal>().ToArray();
                insertRegistrations.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter(attributeDefinition.InternalName, castedLookupValues));
                break;
            case DataType.DateTime:
                var castedDateTimeValues = attributeValues.Cast<DateTime?>().ToArray();
                insertRegistrations.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter(attributeDefinition.InternalName, castedDateTimeValues));
                break;
            case DataType.Boolean:
                // Npgsql is currently not able to handle bool?[], hence this exact type cannot handle null values.
                // This is currently support in v. 5 but since EFCore has a hard dependency on v.4
                // which forces us to use bool[]. 
                var castedBooleanValues = attributeValues.Cast<bool>().ToArray();
                insertRegistrations.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter(attributeDefinition.InternalName, castedBooleanValues));
                break;
        }
    }

    insertRegistrations.Prepare();
    insertRegistrations.CommandTimeout = 0;
    var insertedRowIds = new List<long>();

    using (NpgsqlDataReader dataReader = insertRegistrations.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            insertedRowIds.Add((long)dataReader[0]);
        }
    }

    return insertedRowIds;
}
```

Here I do the validation

```
private IEnumerable<(string, long, NpgsqlRange<DateTime>, bool, NpgsqlRange<DateTime>, long, string, bool)> DetectLookupLifespanViolations(string entityName, IEnumerable<long> entity_ids,
    NpgsqlTransaction transaction)
{
    var sql = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine("SQLQueries", "IntegrityCheck.sql"));
    var integrityCheckCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, transaction.Connection, transaction);
    integrityCheckCommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter<long[]>("@entity_ids", entity_ids.ToArray()));
    integrityCheckCommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter<string>("table_name", entityName));
    var integrity_breached =
        new List<(string, long, NpgsqlRange<DateTime>, bool,  NpgsqlRange<DateTime>, long, string, bool)>();

    var has_values = new NpgsqlCommand($@"select count(*) from {entityName}_registration", transaction.Connection, transaction);
    var result = has_values.ExecuteScalar();
    
    Console.WriteLine(result);

    using NpgsqlDataReader dataReader = integrityCheckCommand.ExecuteReader();
    while (dataReader.Read())
    {
        bool hasDateTimeIntegrity = (bool)(dataReader.GetValue(3) ?? true);
        if (!hasDateTimeIntegrity)
        {
            integrity_breached.Add((dataReader.GetFieldValue<string>(0), 
                    dataReader.GetFieldValue<long>(1),
                    dataReader.GetFieldValue<NpgsqlRange<DateTime>>(2),
                    dataReader.GetFieldValue<bool>(3),
                    dataReader.GetFieldValue<NpgsqlRange<DateTime>>(4),
                    dataReader.GetFieldValue<long>(5),
                    dataReader.GetFieldValue<string>(6),
                    dataReader.GetFieldValue<bool>(7)
                ));
        }
    }

    return integrity_breached;
}
```

The both called within a method were

```
        public bool InsertEntityRegistrations(string entityName, IEnumerable<EntityRegistration> payload)
{

            using var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(configuration.GetConnectionString("PostgreSQL"));
            connection.Open();
            using var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
....
            IEnumerable<long> insertedRowIds = PersistEntityRegistrations(payload, entityName, transaction);

....
            var registrationsCausingIntegrityIssues = DetectLookupLifespanViolations(entityName, allEntityIds, transaction);
...
}
}
```

Comment: You will certainly see the data modified in the transaction from a later statement in the same transaction. Perhaps you are using two different database connections by mistake (pooling?). To get an answer, you must add way more detail.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe i can within the transaction make an select * and get all rows out. its only the npgsqlreader which cannot see this? in the same transaction